# Can't access node value of XML element

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm struggling with an issue, where I'm trying to access the Value of an XML-Element. I can access all the children and attributes, but I just can't seem to get the inner content of the node.

```
var domElement = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlDataString, "application/xml");
$scope.output = domElement.getElementsByTagName("inputEntry")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I've tried .innerHTML, .textContent and .nodeValue, but the output ist always undefined.
The XML-Element I'm trying to access looks like this:

```
<inputEntry id= \"test\">
\n
     <text>\"this should be the output\"</text>
\n
</inputEntry>
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You get there using xpath:

```
var xpath = "//inputEntry/text/text()";
var x = domElement.evaluate(xpath, domElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
console.log(x.snapshotItem(0).textContent);
```

Output:

```
"this should be the output"
```